# Maximize function in Mathematica which counts elements

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I reduced a debugging problem in Mathematica 8 to something similar to the following code:

```
f = Function[x,
 list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5};
 Count[list, x]
];

f[4]
Maximize{f[x], x, Integers]
```

Output:

```
4
{0, {x->0}}
```

So, while the maximum o function f is obtained when x equals 4 (as confirmed in the first output line), why does Maximize return x->0 (output line 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior can be easily found using `Trace`. What happens is that your function is evaluated inside Maximize with still symbolic `x`, and since your list does not contain symbol `x`, results in zero. Effectively, you call `Maximize[0,x,Integers]`, hence the result. One thing you can do is to protect the function from immediate evaluation by using pattern-defined function with a restrictive pattern, like this for example:

```
Clear[ff];
ff[x_?IntegerQ] := 
  With[{list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5}}, Count[list, x]]
```

It appears that `Maximize` can not easily deal with it however, but `NMaximize` can:

```
In[73]:= NMaximize[{ff[x], Element[x, Integers]}, x]

Out[73]= {4., {x -> 4}}
```

But, generally, either of the `Maximize` family functions seem not quite appropriate for the job. You may be better off by explicitly computing the maximum, for example like this:

```
In[78]:= list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5};
Extract[#, Position[#, Max[#], 1, 1] &[#[[All, 2]]]] &[Tally[list]]

Out[79]= {{4, 4}}
```

HTH

Comment: Commonest[list] will get you the most repeated element too

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for reminding. This was somewhere on the back of my mind, but apparently too far :) Besides, OP was interested in the frequency as well, while `Commonest` seems to only provide an element itself

Comment: I think this example is on the borderline between math and programming, so you can do it both ways. But your particular example is clearly more on the programming side, so list manipulations and counting seem more appropriate than functions like `Maximize`, in this particular case.

Comment: The seemingly overcomplicated way to do the count is just an artifact of extracting the relevant part of the code, without reflecting the overall objective of the function. The true objective was to use Minimize on a function doing a Monte Carlo simulation, which returns a value that is the difference between the requested probability of occurrences and the number obtained in the simulation. I'm still trying to adapt the original code based on the answer provided here.

Comment: @Leonid {#[[2, 1]], Count[#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]]} &@{#, Commonest[#]} &@list

Comment: Or SortBy[Tally[list], -#[[2]] &][[1]]

Comment: @belisarius  Sure, there are ways. But when we include these, the code size is comparable to what I suggested. I think `Commonest` could have an option to return the frequency as well, since this is a natural thing to ask, or just plain return it together with the element, in all cases.

Comment: @Leonid Tally does almost that, only the results are not ordered, so First@SortBy[Tally[list], -#[[2]] &] does it

Comment: @belisarius Yeah, true. For large lists this can get slower though, due to the N log N complexity of Sort. In practice, lists should be pretty large to observe this, a few millions elements at least. For 20 mils I get 3x slowdown, for example. But for integers, both methods are still quite fast, since `SortBy`, `Tally` etc are optimized for packed arrays.

Comment: @Leonid For example for list=Round[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 1000000], .10]; your solution and the SortBy one have equivalent performance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5};
First@Sort[Tally[list], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]
```

Output:

```
{4, 4}
```